# Magento 2 : How to set Price in bundle Products

Tags: magento2, orders, cart, bundled-product

I'm having this issue when i am making an order programatically and i am setting them to 0 the price, this  can be made with simple, virtual and even configurable products with this code:

```
$cartItem = $cart->addProduct($product, $objParam);
$cartItem->setCustomPrice(0.0);
$cartItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0.0);
$cartItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$cartItem->save();
```

The issue is that from here i can't  have with bundles the subtotals with 0:
[image]

As i was saying... the subtotal sets normally with 0 with simples, virtuals and configurables, but with Bundles is not happening :(
But when I do that with Bundle Products is not setting to 0... Does anyone can help me with this issue please ? I'll appreciated it

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- Event for add to cart -->
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="namespace_customprice_observer_set_price_for_item_add" instance="Namespace\CustomPrice\Model\Observer\SetPriceForItem"/>
    </event>
    <!-- Event for update add to cart -->
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_update_after">
        <observer name="namespace_customprice_observer_set_price_for_item_update" instance="Namespace\CustomPrice\Model\Observer\SetPriceForItem"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

After that need an observer at

> app/code/Namespace/CustomPrice/Model/Observer/SetPriceForItem.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\CustomPrice\Model\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;

class SetPriceForItem implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * Add Special Price on add to cart.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return SetPriceForItem
     *
     */
     public function execute(Observer $observer)
     {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
        if ($item->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
            foreach ($item->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $bundleitems) {
                /** @var $bundleitems\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
                //Skip the bundle product
                if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                    $bundleitems->setCustomPrice(1.00);
                    $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice(1.00); 
                    $bundleitems->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                }   
            }
            $item->setCustomPrice(0);
            $item->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
            $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        }
        return $this;
     }
}
```

Comment: HI there,  i added the observer and also in events but i still have the subtotal not with 0 in the orders:
Product Name  SKU  Price  Qty  Subtotal
Sprite Yoga Companion Kit
 24-WG080-24-WG081-blue-24-WG084-24-WG085-24-WG088  $0.00     $42.09

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your cart page and code of your observer file?

Comment: The idea here is have the subtotal with 0 but its not happening :(

Comment: I've updated the question Abhishek ... with the bundles in Orders view there you have it the screenshot

Comment: My observer is like you did, but the difference is this: 
if ($bundleitems->getProduct()->getTypeId() == Type::TYPE_BUNDLE) {
                    $bundleitems->setCustomPrice(0);
                    $bundleitems->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);
                    $bundleitems->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                }

Comment: Check my updated code :)

Comment: Sorry i cant get the subtotal with 0 according with your code

Comment: Any other idea? :(